# How to update authentication token for mp4 file with JW Player?

Tags: authentication, cloudflare, jwplayer, hmac, http-token-authentication

I am using JW Player for embedding videos on a website. I have protected the (mp4 file) video URLs with token authentication using [Cloudflare's token authentication](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/firewall/learn-more/configuring-token-authentication/#option-2-configure-using-waf-custom-rules). However, since the video URLs have an expiration time, a video link might expire while it is still being played in a visitor browser causing the video playback to end abruptly. Therefore, I need to refresh the authentication token in the video URL. The only thing that needs to be changed is the token query parameter in the URL. (The URI path stays the same.) How can I do that in JW Player without causing the video playback to restart?